# Get Azure AD Basic User Profile

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get the users basic profile from Azure AD. I have a React Native app authenticating against a *Native* Azure AD *App registration*. The `access_token` I got from that request is used to authenticate against a *Web app / Api*. The user is shown the propper consent screen with the permissions I set in Azure AD.

1. Microsoft Graph API

   - Read all users' basic profiles
   - Sign in and read user profile
2. Windows Azure Active Directory

   - Read all users' basic profiles
   - Sign in and read user profile

(added both Graph API & AAD because I didn't know which one to use)

When I try and get the users profile through https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me, with the `access_token` gotten from the previous request I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token validation failure.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "00cdb708-bcf8-4b33-af21-14a046b16533",
            "date": "2018-09-02T18:28:59"
        }
    }
}
```

The `resource` in my initial authentication request is the *Web App / API's* app id, and I don't think having 2 resources is an option (?).

What am I doing wrong, and what should I do to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to your descriptions, I assume you want to get the users profile, but get the error shows an invalid token.

Based on my test, the request URL that you posted is not correct.

It should be 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me' or 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}'.

We can trouble shoot your problems as follows.

First, check request, if it has correct 'Authorization' field. [This document](http://%20%20%20https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get#request-headers) shows that we need the Authorization field in the request headers.

Second, if you have added the Authorization field in the request headers, could you provide the main code that we can identify if problem is from there ?

Comment: The `access_token` request. This works for getting a token that can be used in the API:  `'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=' +AAD_NATIVE_ID+ '&response_type=token&reply_url=' +AAD_API_REPLY_URL+ '&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&scope=openid&nonce=678910&resource=' + AAD_API_ID.`. This is what I request to get the profile `let fetchString = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me"  
        request.open('GET', fetchString);  
        request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token)  
        request.send(); `

Comment: As you posted, your scope is for  openid. When we get the user, according to [this document] (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get#permissions) the scope need 
User.Read.

Comment: I get the same `Access token validation failure` when changing the endpoint to:  
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=' +AAD_NATIVE_ID+ '&response_type=token&reply_url=' +AAD_API_REPLY_URL+ '&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&scope=openid+User.Read&prompt=admin_consent&nonce=678910&resource=' + AAD_API_ID `

Comment: The URL should be like this: `fetchString = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"`

Comment: I just changed the `fetchString` to what you requested, but still get the error: _InvalidAuthenticationToken_.

Comment: I check the authorization endpoint, it not correct match the document.We can refert to this document https://developer.microsoft.com/zh-cn/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user

Answer (score 0):

While getting the access token add "**resource**" : "https://graph.microsoft.com/" and use that access token in header with **Bearer** than hit the url ---> https://graph.microsoft.com/me?api-version=1.6

**Don't forget to add the resource while getting access token**

Thank me later :P